# Create a simple store procedure in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I am looking to create a simple store procedureto return a list of all user names in a table called dba_users.

The select I am using is:

```
SELECT username FROM dba_users
```

When I create a PROCEDURE with the following syntax it is created, but fails to execute:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user_list_display
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT username FROM dba_users
END;
```

For this I get

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement:
EXECUTE user_list_display;
```

Comment: @PM77-1, you can use either `AS` or `IS`, [plsql_procedure_source](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54__BABJEGID)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: Pardon me asking, but - what is the purpose of putting a simple `SELECT username FROM dba_users` into a *procedure*? What benefit do you expect?

Comment: For one simple select, no purpose except understanding how to do it right. I've just started working with oracle, and I'll need to write a store procedure with a more complex set of selects, inserts, etc. for testing a certain product.
For now, I just want to learn how to do a simple one, as all the options I tried failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had better using an `implicit cursor` with `dbms_output.put_line`:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user_list_display IS
BEGIN
FOR c in ( SELECT username FROM dba_users )
LOOP
 dbms_output.put_line(c.username);
END LOOP;
END;
/
SQL> exec user_list_display;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is the best and simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle12c, You can use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user_list_display
IS
v_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN v_cursor FOR SELECT username FROM dba_users;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT ( v_cursor );
END;
/
```

Then execute it as

```
EXEC user_list_display;
```

In lower versions,from SQL* Plus (or execute as script in SQL Developer ), you may use a `REFCURSOR`  `OUT` variable  and `PRINT` to display the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user_list_display( output OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
IS
BEGIN
OPEN output FOR SELECT username FROM dba_users;
END;
/
```

You may run these 3 lines whenever you want to see the output.

```
VARIABLE output REFCURSOR
EXEC user_list_display(:output)
PRINT output
```